# Can't manage to make $_POST to work

Tags: php, post

I have three files in a server **(000webhost.com)**:
"**Test01.php**" (main file),
"**database.txt**" (saved data, which will be changed by users),
"**save_txt.php**" (the file which gets data from the main file and writes it to the "database".

"**Test01.php**" is supposed to show a simple list, with a few names in a table (single column, multiple lines).
Those names will be retrieved from a file named "**database.txt**".
Everytime some user click on a name, that name will be sent to the bottom of the list, and the list will be saved to "**database.txt**", so the next user will see the changes made by the last one.
A function in "**Test01.php**" sends the changed list to a second file ("**save_txt.php**"), which is supposed to write it back to "**database.txt**".

I can manage to retrieve the data from the txt file, and the clicking events as well, but I still can't find a way to save the data into the txt file...
In fact, I don't understand why my variable isn't seen from inside the second php file ("**save_txt.php**").

To retrieve data I use:

```
    <?php
       $Data_from_File = file("database.txt",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    ?>
```

And the script:

```
var sSaved_Data = <?php echo json_encode($Data_from_File); ?>;
```

The listing stuff works fine.
I get many names from the txt file and store it into an array. Then I display it in the table. No problem from reading the file.

I send data to "**save_txt.php**" by doing this:

```
var sNew_Data = " is blue";
.
.
.
xmlhttp.send("php_Data_to_Save=" + sNew_Data);
```

But, could anyone tell me why the simple code below doesn't work?

https://rbonphp.000webhostapp.com/Test01.php

"**save_txt.php**" is just like this:

```
<?php
   $var1 = $_POST["php_Data_to_Save"];
   echo $var1;
?>
```

In time: in this example I just want to see **" is blue"** echoed in the screen **(no matter where)**. I just want to understand how to get the data back to "**save_txt.php**".
Later I will try to write **$var1** to **"database.txt"**.
But first things first...
:-(

As I said, this "**Test01.php**" is just a test. The list and all the clicking events I wrote in another file. That part works just fine.

*** Edited ***

Let's try to put it all in a few lines.
The main file (**Test01.php**) does:

```
var sNew_Data = " is blue";      
// there's more code for the XMLHttpRequest function
xmlhttp.send("php_Data_to_Save=" + sNew_Data);
```

The secondary file (**save_txt.php**) does:

```
<?php
  $var1 = $_POST["php_Data_to_Save"];
  echo $var1;
?> // and this is ALL its code, just these 4 lines.
```

That line **echo $var1;** should simply show **" is blue"** on the screen.
  Right???

Extra info: Test01.php is a step prior to make the following page to work:

https://rbonphp.000webhostapp.com/DailyTasks1.php

Comment: You have over complicated your problem and haven't given a proper question. Is your PHP not working? Is the XML request not sending?
Simplify what the problem is and explain your current output and your desired output. I can't see from your link how you are expecting to put input into the database.

Comment: @MinistryofChaps, as I said "in this example I just want to see 'is blue' echoed in the screen (no matter where)". The other stuff I got it working. Well, some I still don't, but it's not the purpose of this question, which is to understand why the $_POST is not working.

Comment: There's no code in your question that would look at the response and put it on the screen.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: How come? @Quentin, that's what the **echo $var1** in save_txt.php is supposed to do, right?

Comment: @RGeral — That puts it in the HTTP response. It has nothing to do with what the JS renders on screen. (Well, unless there is JS code which renders the response on screen … which there isn't in the question).

Comment: I put all the code needed to understand my problem, @Quentin. First I said how I send data from the main file (**Test01.php**), which is the one the user access. Then I said how I expect to retrieve that data in the server, from within the secondary file (**save_txt.php**). The problem is: the variable sent by **Test01.php** is not being received by **save_txt.php**. All the code related to that operation is the question.

Comment: "The problem is: the variable sent by Test01.php is not being received by save_txt.php." — How can you tell? Describe the process you used to determine this. There's no evidence of any code in the question that would inspect it. You have only mentioned that it isn't echoed onto the screen … but there's no code in the question that would do that.

Comment: I don't get it... @Quentin. The title of my question is **"Can't manage to make $_POST to work"**. The file **"save_txt.php"** has only 4 lines of code. It is in the question. And that's where I need help, cause it seems to me that **$var1** should receive the value from **sNew_Data**.

Comment: @RGeral — Yes, it should. Do you have any reason to think it doesn't other than the fact that it isn't displayed on your screen? Because, since you haven't included any code in the question which would make it display on the screen, it looks like you've misdiagnosed the problem and `$var1` does contain that value.

Comment: I'm confused... of course @Quentin, for a beginner. What does **echo $var1;** should do?... I posted this question believing that the 4 lines of code from **save_txt.php** should be enough to display **is blue** on the screen. As I said, no matter where. If you're telling me that **$var1** does contain the value from **sNew_Data**, then what am I missing? Cause this is the whole point of this question... Once I can get a value from **Test01.php** in **save_txt.php**, then I will work on saving it to the txt file on the server. But I still can't simply see that **echo $var1** working!

Comment: "What does echo $var1; should do?." — It puts the value of `$var1` in the HTTP response.

Comment: "I posted this question believing that the 4 lines of code from save_txt.php should be enough to display ** is blue** on the screen. " — It isn't. You are making the request with XMLHttpRequest. It does not cause the browser to navigate to a new page. You are not submitting a form. You are not following a link. You are not typing a URL into the address bar.

Comment: Well @Quentin,guess I'm wrong from the very beginning then... but what I added in my editing was already in the question, since the first time I posted it. I was saying and showing the code, right from the start, believing that **echo $var1** should do the work, believing that the problem was the **$_POST**. Anyway, I have no ideia why the **echo** doesn't work, since **$var1** has the value. But even though it's not clear to me, can I start working on a routine to save **$var1** to a **txt file** on the server? I mean, the code will be in **save_txt.php**, of course...

Comment: I suggest you learn how to use the development tools in your browser to inspect the response and how to use XMLHttpRequest to access the response (which any introductory tutorial should tell you) so that you can actually debug your code before you try to make it more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code **is** working.
Calling `Send_Data_to_Server()` returns "The sky is blue" which is what you wanted, as the sent data is `var sNew_Data = sSaved_Data + " is blue";` and it is correctly echoed by **save_txt.php**

Note: your commented jquery ajax call is wrong however, that's not how you define the sent data, check the first example at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

You'd write this:

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'save_txt.php',
      data: { php_Data_to_Save : sNew_Data },
      type: 'POST'
});
```

Comment: What??? Can't believe I missed that one (to call Send_Data_to_Server())... anyway, I've been searching and trying to make it work the whole morning and that's not the reason it didn't work. I mean, not alone. Just updated this example code and it's not working yet. My local network problem maybe??? I will try the jquery later, but I didn't want to use jquery...

Comment: You don't really need jquery, I just thought you wanted that since it was there. The point is, your script works - to get the data back to "save_txt.php". Now you just update the txt file with the received data in save_text.php and refresh your list in some way - eg. return the new list to Test01 or just return true and reload Test01 or just return the change etc.

Comment: did you change the code to make it work somehow? Because when I open Test01.php (from that link in the server, of course) the only thing I see is "The sky", and then a pop window saying "done". The words "is blue" are never shown to me, as I simply expected to...

Comment: Funny thing... I had set my mind to the fact that the **echo** would do something that it actually doesn't, and didn't try to move on. I completed the **save_txt.php** file, in order to see what happens, and everything's fine @Manny.... Now I will work on processing my data the right way.

Answer (score 0):

first, you didnt call `Send_Data_to_Server()` anywhere, you've just declared it.

secont, you just send the request to server, but don't store the answer anywhere.

Comment: As I just said, I forgot to call Send_Data_to_Server() in this example, but I was calling it in my previous files and it's not working yet. Can't understand how @Manny saw it working... And the data is not supposed to be stored by this time. Just want it to be echoed. Which I can't get.